# Using Excel x y scatter chart as a line of balance scheduling

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

It is possible to add automatically more series to one X Y (Scatter) chart?
Maybe by some VBA?
The problem is that for every x and y I have two values. The example is in the screenshot below.

[image]

There is no problem to add a few series to one chart bat when you have 500 series - there is a big problem.
Please let me know if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that there is a limit of 255 series per chart. If you can keep within that, these procedures will help.

To create a new chart using the data in the table:

```
Sub InsertNewChart()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Chart
  cht.ChartArea.ClearContents
  Dim iRow As Long
  For iRow = 2 To ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .Name = "=" & ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Address(, , , True)
      .Values = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Resize(, 2)
      .XValues = ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Resize(, 2)
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

To extend an existing chart by one series, using data in the row after the last series in the chart:

```
Sub ExtendChart()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = ActiveChart
  Dim sFmla As String
  sFmla = cht.SeriesCollection(cht.SeriesCollection.Count).Formula
  sFmla = Mid$(Left$(sFmla, Len(sFmla) - 1), InStr(sFmla, "(") + 1)
  Dim vFmla As Variant
  vFmla = Split(sFmla, ",")
  Dim rName As Range
  Set rName = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla)))
  Dim rXVals As Range
  Set rXVals = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla) + 1))
  Dim rYVals As Range
  Set rYVals = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla) + 2))
  With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "=" & rName.Offset(1).Address(, , , True)
    .XValues = rXVals.Offset(1)
    .Values = rYVals.Offset(1)
  End With
End Sub
```

To extend a chart as above, but adding one series per row until you run out of data:

```
Sub KeepExtendingChart()
  Dim cht As Chart
  Set cht = ActiveChart
  Do
    Dim sFmla As String
    sFmla = cht.SeriesCollection(cht.SeriesCollection.Count).Formula
    sFmla = Mid$(Left$(sFmla, Len(sFmla) - 1), InStr(sFmla, "(") + 1)
    Dim vFmla As Variant
    vFmla = Split(sFmla, ",")
    Dim rName As Range
    Set rName = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla)))
    If Len(rName.Offset(1).Value) = 0 Then Exit Do
    Dim rXVals As Range
    Set rXVals = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla) + 1))
    Dim rYVals As Range
    Set rYVals = Range(vFmla(LBound(vFmla) + 2))
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .Name = "=" & rName.Offset(1).Address(, , , True)
      .XValues = rXVals.Offset(1)
      .Values = rYVals.Offset(1)
    End With
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I GOT THE SAME PROBLEM MANY TIME AGO, WHAT I AM DOING NOW IS THE LISTED BELOW:

DO YOUR SCHEDULE IN P6 ASSIGNING A CODE TO INDICATE START AND FINISH LOCATION FOR EACH ACTIVITY.
THEN WHEN SCHEDULED EXPORT IT TO EXCEL YOU WILL HAVE ALL THE STARTS WITH DATE AND LOCATION (FIRST COORDINATE) SAME WITH FINISH.

THEN USE THIS COORDINATES PREVIUSLY ARRANGED IN EXCEL TO EXPORT AND DRAW AUTOMATICALLY ON AUTOCAD.

Another Way is using Turbo Chart.

Comment: Please do not write in all capitals - it is considered shouting and is hard to read.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1164500)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).